# assignment of packed bitfield struct gives wrong values

Tags: c

I have a packed structure which should be 16 bits:

```
#pragma pack(1)

typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned short ushort;

typedef struct Color Color;
struct Color
{
    uint r : 5;
    uint g : 5;
    uint b : 5;
    uint _ : 1;
};
```

I have confirmed that

```
&(((Color*)0x06000000)[x]) == &(((ushort*)0x06000000)[x])
```

For various values of x. However, in this code, these two lines give me different results.

```
void write_pixel (uint x, uint y, Color color)
{
    #if 0
    ((Color*)0x06000000)[x+y*240] = color;
    #else
     ((ushort*)0x06000000)[x+y*240] = ((ushort*)&color)[0];
    #endif
}
```

With the second option being correct.

What could be the cause?

*note. I'm compiling for GBA emulator so no debugger or printf, just yes/no statements by way of a green/red pixel.*

Comment: what result do you get? short is 16 bits on this platform?(just checking)

Comment: if I write_pixel (0,31,31) I get a cyan pixel using the second path, but a white pixel using the first path. I'm pretty sure short is 16 bits on this platform, but in any case, the Color struct and an unsigned short are teh same size.

Comment: Why not use `int16_t` and be sure?

Comment: Just tried it, they are the same size.

Comment: can u look at the generated assembly code?

Comment: You've verified the struct is the size you think it is? You can count sixteen bytes specified, but due to alignment the actual size isn't necessarily 16.

Comment: @pm100 I've tried passing -S and -save-temps to gcc but it doesn't seem to be saving the assembly anywhere...

Comment: @WalterDelevich the #pragma pack(1) removes the alignment and I've verified that sizeof(Color) == sizeof(uint16_t)

Comment: The idea of bitfields is that the complier makes al this nasty masks to get/set the value. So why don't you just use the syntax? For example `struct Color myPixel; myPixel.r= 31;`

Comment: I'm surprised you have `0x06000000` written more than once.  Surely, it would be better to have `Color *screen_base = (Color *)0x06000000;` somewhere, and then use `screen_base[x + y * 240] = ...`.  Or `#define SCREEN_BASE ((Color *)0x06000000)` and `SCREEN_BASE[x + y * 240]`.  Or something similar.  We can debate about the wisdom of using a hardwired 240, too.  It would be better to make that an enum value, such as `enum { SCR_WIDTH = 240 };`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, sorry, I don't understand. The purpose behind defining the Color struct like this was precisely in order to use that syntax.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, these are good suggestions for a code review but I doubt that the naming choices or magic numbers are what is causing my current problem.

Comment: @evenex_code: Indubitably, which is why they're a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm well aware of the dangers of magic constants, but these were some scratch debug code in a temporary 50-line file. Best practices don't apply, it's like I'm looking for something I lose in the cabin of my car and someone comes to tell me that I ought to wear a seatbelt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the value seen from the parameter list is going to be (due to promotion of parameters) as an unsigned int (32bits).  then the incorrect line is trying to copy a 32bit unsigned int into a 16bit short.

Normally this would work  However the pragma modifies how the 16bit Color is being placed in the promoted parameter and/or how the code is referencing the 16bits of Color.

```
While packed values are (normally) not promoted,
if there is no prototype for the called function
then all parameters are assumed to 'int' 
so the code assumes the data is (sizeof int) bytes long (4 bytes)
and the assignment takes the last 2 bytes
of that 4 byte value rather than the first 2 bytes.
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable: when I rewrite the assignment to assign individual fields, then change the order of assignment, I get different results. How frustrating, is there a way to use these bitfields in the way I'm intending? (for named color channels and to reinterpret-cast pixels in the video memory)